# Search and get Key in Multidimensional Array

Tags: php, arrays

I have multidimensional array and I need to search for top level key by the value in "add_fields" arrays by "value". I cannot figure out I can achieve the result. Can somebody help me?

I was googling it and found several solutions but I was not able to get any result.

Trying this code

```
array_search('001001', array_column(array_column($arr, "usr_column_504"), 0)),
```

but didn't get anything and I need to get top level key. In this example its **0**;

```
array (
    0 => 
        array (
          'id' => 1,
          'group_id' => 327,
          'volume' => 0,
          'vat' => 1,
          'order_id' => 1,
          'add_fields' => 
          array (
            1 => 
            array (
              'field' => 'usr_column_501',
              'value' => '',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'field' => 'usr_column_504',
              'value' => '001001',
            ),
          ),
        ),
    1 => 
        array (
          'id' => 2,
          'group_id' => 327,
          'vat' => 1,
          'order_id' => 2,
          'add_fields' => 
          array (
            1 => 
            array (
              'field' => 'usr_column_501',
              'value' => '',
            ),
            2 => 
            array (
              'field' => 'usr_column_504',
              'value' => '001002',
            ),
          ),
        ),
)
```

Comment: you know how this works, please show us your best attempt(code) - what is the actual outcome, what is desired, any error(s), have you done any debugging?

Comment: Edited question. But I'm not getting any errors, just empty array()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the first key where the value of `field` equals `usr_column_504` you could use an outer and an inner foreach.

When the value of field is found, return the `$key` from the outer foreach.

```
foreach ($arr as $key => $item) {  
    foreach ($item["add_fields"] as $addField) {
        if ($addField["field"] === "usr_column_504") {
            echo $key;
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Output

```
0
```

[Php demo](https://3v4l.org/Xvic9)